# Squid cache problem

Tags: proxy, squid, http-proxy

If I put in my `test_site acl` (deny access policy) a site (i.e, www.aaabbbccc.com) which nobody ever accessed and do a `squid -k reconfigure`, Squid then appears to correctly log the site.

I then comment out the www.aaabbbccc.com URL in the test_site acl and run `squid -k reconfigure` again. So Squid allows the access to the site, correctly, doing a cache.

But, here's the problem. If I remove the comment in the test_site acl, run again `squid -k reconfigure`, and I'm still able to access the URL www.aaabbbccc.com (I clean my machine cache already).

My conclusion is that squid can deny a site which is stored in the squid cache. But it doesn't make any sense. Am I right?

Here´s my `squid.conf`

```
*#####################################################################################
ie_refresh on
#####################################################################################
acl all src 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8
acl SSL_ports   port    443
acl Safe_ports  port    21
acl Safe_ports  port    443
acl Safe_ports  port    1025-65535

####################################################################################
acl NOCACHE url_regex "/etc/squid/regras/nocachesites"
####################################################################################
acl liberar_mac_x                arp "/etc/squid/regras/liberar_mac_x"
####################################################################################
# Regras de Controle
####################################################################################
acl test_site               url_regex -i "/etc/squid/regras/teste_lucas"
acl redelocal   src     192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0
acl purge method PURGE
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

####################################################################################
no_cache deny NOCACHE

http_access allow liberar_mac_x
http_access deny teste_lucas
http_access allow redelocal

http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access allow purge localhost
http_access deny purge
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all

icp_access allow all
####################################################################################
http_port       3128    transparent
####################################################################################
cache_mem       256     MB
####################################################################################
#cache_dir      ufs     /var/spool/squid 2000 32 512
cache_dir       ufs     /home/squid 5000 32 256
####################################################################################
access_log      /var/log/squid/access.log squid
log_fqdn        on
####################################################################################
acl QUERY urlpath_regex cgi-bin \?
cache deny QUERY
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
####################################################################################
acl apache rep_header Server ^Apache
broken_vary_encoding allow apache

####################################################################################
cache_effective_user    proxy
cache_effective_group   proxy
visible_hostname        Servidor_de_Proxy
####################################################################################
error_directory /usr/share/squid/errors/Portuguese
####################################################################################
ignore_expect_100 on
####################################################################################
always_direct allow all
####################################################################################
*
```

Comment: check permission of `/etc/squid/regras/liberar_mac_x`